# How to save Username instead of Object name(None) automatically while saving the model in django

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, admin

[check the updated pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKtQx.png)

When I save the model, The object name is None, but I need to save the username instead  of object name (None) automatically while I saving the Model

[here is pic of admin site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLOWv.png)

Models.py

```
class solo_21_6_2021(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player1_pubg_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    player1_pubg_name = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True,blank=True)
 

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Views.py

```
def solo(request):
   form = SoloForm()
   if request.method=="POST":
      form=SoloForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          form.save()

   return render(request, 'bgmiapp/solo.html',{'form':form})
```

Forms.py

```
    class SoloForm(forms.ModelForm):
         class Meta():
            model = solo_21_6_2021
            fields=['player1_pubg_id','player1_pubg_name'
```

Admin.py

```
    class SoloAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list = ('user','player1_pubg_id','player1_pubg_name')


    admin.site.register(Profile)
    admin.site.register(solo_21_6_2021,SoloAdmin)
```

Comment: Your table also shows few usernames in admin. What does those ```None``` fields show when you open ?

Comment: you have `null=True` which makes me think you're not setting the username in the first place

Comment: it is not automaticaly done sir,i edit that,and i have user onetoone field, so i just use the username

Comment: any solution sir

Comment: Open those ```None``` fields and see what data you have there. Do you see any ```username``` there ?

Comment: i just added another pic check that sir

Comment: @RajeshKumar  That's not a ```None``` fields data.

Comment: sorry sir,check now

Comment: @RajeshKumar It has no ```username``` and that's why you are getting ```None```. Do as @taha maatof suggested in the answer and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have set user field to null so the model is created without it, so when you want to show objects by user, it does not have this info so it shows None.

modify models to :

```
class solo_21_6_2021(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  player1_pubg_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
  player1_pubg_name = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=True,blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
      return str(self.user)
```

so now it is required and related as it is supposed to be

and inf the forms:

```
class SoloForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = solo_21_6_2021
        fields=['user','player1_pubg_id','player1_pubg_name']
```

so it display the choice of user in the html form

now when you submit the form, the user name will display in the admin page

**Alternatively* you could make your authenticated user the one who is creating the object, so no need to show list of your users to everyone:

```
def solo(request):
    form = SoloForm()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=SoloForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.save(commit=False)
            f.user = request.user
            f.save()

return render(request, 'bgmiapp/solo.html',{'form':form})
```

and get rid of user in forms:

```
class SoloForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = solo_21_6_2021
        fields=['player1_pubg_id','player1_pubg_name']
```

**Ps:** since you have a OnetoOne relation, you can create only one object by user, creating another will throw a user_id unique constraint error

Comment: thanks for those steps,but please give one last solution, if i can create one object by User,then how can i create the another object with the user